# facing following message Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Wait' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select Branch_Code,Branch_Name,Sector,Region_name,SUM(case when Days_Number =0 then 1 else 0 end  )as  Same_Day,SUM(case when Days_Number =1 then 1 else 0 end)as  Next_DAy, SUM(case when Days_Number =2 then 1 else 0 end)as  After_Two_Days,SUM(case when Days_Number >2 then 1 else 0 end)as Same_Week,sum(case when Days_Number = 'Wait' then 1 else 0 end)as  Not_Installed_Yet from Main_Report_Working_Area where Starting_Date>=@Starting_Date and Starting_Date2<=@Starting_Date2  and ADV_Code =20  group by Branch_Code,Branch_Name,sector,Region_name", connsqlserver)
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Wait' to data type int

Comment: What is the data type of `Days_Number`?

Comment: the type is nvarchar(50)

Comment: Well...'Wait' is not a valid number which is seems it must be. I would urge you to format your queries. This thing is horrible to decipher all slammed onto a single line like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is comparing NVARCHAR values to integers: `Days_Number = 1`. It would work fine if all those values looked like numbers, but apparently you have values like `'Wait'` and this is causing a problem.

You can work around this using ISNUMERIC() function. I've formatted SQL string from your example and added it.

```
select
    Branch_Code,
    Branch_Name,
    Sector,
    Region_name,
    SUM(case
        when ISNUMERIC(Days_Number) = 1
        and Days_Number = 0 then 1
        else 0 end) as Same_Day,
    SUM(case 
        when ISNUMERIC(Days_Number) = 1
        and Days_Number = 1 then 1
        else 0 end) as Next_DAy,
    SUM(case
        when ISNUMERIC(Days_Number) = 1
        and Days_Number = 2 then 1
        else 0 end) as After_Two_Days,
    SUM(case
        when ISNUMERIC(Days_Number) = 1
        and Days_Number > 2 then 1
        else 0 end) as Same_Week,
    sum(case
        when Days_Number = 'Wait' then 1
        else 0 end) as Not_Installed_Yet
from Main_Report_Working_Area
where Starting_Date >= @Starting_Date
and Starting_Date2 <= @Starting_Date2
and ADV_Code = 20
group by
    Branch_Code,
    Branch_Name,
    sector,
    Region_name
```

Comment: You would have to use string literals in your case expressions instead of ints. And there really is no need for ISNUMERIC. This of course is all based on your assumption that the datatype of Days_Number is varchar and not a number.

Comment: Thank You very Much For help